# Campy Alien Horror movie with Alien Stowaway on Lunar Lander?

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, horror

About 10 years ago my brother and I were flipping channels and we came across a movie that we have been looking for ever since.

All we really remember is that some kind of slimy alien was stowed away on some spacecraft that humans brought​ back to Earth (possibly the lunar lander) and no one notices it until it starts to kill them all.

It took place at NASA headquarters or something and I specifically remember a scene where the alien is hiding in the ceiling of a bathroom and kills someone in a stall.

Comment: I fear this is too unspecific. I remember at least 5 bad movies I also channel flipped into (and short time later out from) that perfectly match your description. Do you remember anything unique? Perhaps how the alien looks like? Or his method of killing?

Comment: Was the monster made of slime? or was it just slimy?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! If I remember correctly - it was made actually slime because it would squeeze through small areas. It didnt really have a form at all.

Comment: Did the alien ride to Earth on a Viking probe that mysteriously comes back from mars?  Sounds like Lifeform (1996).

Comment: THATS IT!!! Thank you soooo much!!! That has been bugging me for years!

Comment: @Matt, glad to help.  Formal answer posted.

Comment: @Matt since you've confirmed this is _Lifeform_, you can formally accept Dosco's answer by clicking the checkmark on the left. Please do; it will show everyone the mystery was solved, and reward both you and Dosco with some reputation :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Movie where an alien pod landed at an arctic base](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/227321/movie-where-an-alien-pod-landed-at-an-arctic-base) - see OP confirmation above

Answer (score 5):

This is the 1996 movie *[Lifeform](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116646/)*.

> When the Viking space capsule suddenly returns to Earth from its long ago trip to Mars, it brings with it an intelligent visitor that is part "Alien" and part "ET". Encased in armor, it extends a humanlike form from its shell to examine its surroundings and shows an interest in humans including a soft caress of a female scientist prior to the Army killing it. This only enrages its sibling.

The creators tried hard to make a good SF movie.
They almost succeeded.

There are videos on the internet for the curious.

### Trailer