# Movie with a returning probe/satellite, an alien infection, and a nuke at the end

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I've been trying to find the name of a movie I remember seeing on TV on several occasions. What I remember of the plot:

1. A probe/satellite returns to earth
2. It's brought to an underground facility and is studied
3. An alien bacteria onboard spreads, taking over the computer, infecting people and growing into a monster (John Carpenter/The Thing style)
4. The facility is nuked at the end of the movie to kill it off, but you see the alien escaped the facility, walking off-screen as the bomb goes off.

I've been scouring lists of sci-fi movies to no avail. Sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: Elements of this match [The Andromeda Strain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YMbSpnlOOtE)

Comment: My first thought as well, but I assume you deleted your answer because the end doesn't match.

Comment: I just saw a movie called Lifeform on YouTube today. The Viking probe returned and carried an alien egg that grew to an adult. Another egg was laid in the facility, and that creature had the memories of the alien which laid it. They nuked the facility at the end. The alien was outside the facility but got nuked. At the end you saw his dust blow away, leaving an egg lying on the desert. Vitter Smith and a young Ryan Phillipe. http://www.the-unknown-movies.com/unknownmovies/reviews/rev120.html

Comment: @OrganicMarble - Yup. I missed point #4 on my first look-through

Comment: Auto correct changed my comment and I didn't notice. It was Cotter Smith in the movie, not Vitter.

Comment: I was also thinking Lifeform.  It came up a couple of weeks ago:  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/203222/campy-alien-horror-movie-with-alien-stowaway-on-lunar-lander/203314#203314

Comment: When you say you saw it on TV on several occasions, can you give a time frame, country (USA/UK/CAN/AUS other), perhaps channel name?

Comment: @MorrisonChang USA, can't remember when exactly. UHF, we didn't have cable.

Comment: @ArlettaS That's it! Do you want to post that as an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The movie is *[Lifeform](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116646/plotsummary)* with Cotter Smith and Ryan Phillippe.

> When the Viking space capsule suddenly returns to Earth from its long ago trip to Mars, it brings with it an intelligent visitor that is part "Alien" and part "ET". Encased in armor, it extends a humanlike form from its shell to examine its surroundings and shows an interest in humans including a soft caress of a female scientist prior to the Army killing it. This only enrages its sibling.

The Viking probe returned and carried an alien egg that grew to an adult. Another egg was laid in the facility, and that creature had the memories of the alien which laid it. They nuked the facility at the end. The alien was outside the facility but got nuked. At the end you saw his dust blow away, leaving an egg lying on the desert.

The review [here](https://the-unknown-movies.com/unknownmovies/reviews/rev120.html) provides more details, including that the base being nuked was the result of them running out of money, preventing the original ending.

[image: Cover of "Lifeform", special edition. "There's something out there, and it's found a way in." The Earth is visible against a dark starry background. There is a purplish face at the top, with only the eyes and just above visible. There is a purple streak heading from the face down towards the Earth.]