# 80s/90s movie with a centaur-shaped alien trapped in a military base

Tags: story-identification, movie

The movies is from the 80s-90s. A centaur-shaped alien is trapped in a military base, builds a death ray at the end of the movie, folds a man in half in one scene.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: This question seems to be an exercise in terseness. Can you expand on what you mean by a centaur-shape alien? Where was the military base? Who were the military, humans or other aliens? Was the centaur a villain? What did the death ray accomplish? Why was he going around folding people in half?

Comment: This is a duplicate of the several other questions related to the Lifeform movie.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/205005/movie-with-a-returning-probe-satellite-an-alien-infection-and-a-nuke-at-the-en

Answer (score 4):

Could this be *[Lifeform](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116646/?ref_=tt_urv)* (AKA *Invader*) from 1996? The titular lifeform is a sort of horse-alien thing trapped on a military base. At the end it turns some comms equipment into a weapon.

[image: Military-type man seen from behind, wearing a helmet, targeted by a ray of light handled by a thin blurry creature]