# Movie with an alien that infiltrates a space station. Eventually the entire facility gets nuked

Tags: story-identification

I saw this movie on TV, it was around 1995 - 2000? The general plot is that an alien life form is a stowaway on an Earth ship. It escapes into a NASA-like station and is hunted down by the staff. In the end it and the entire facility and staff are destroyed by a nuclear blast as the creature howls with the full moon in the background.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Nuke it from orbit, only way to be sure

Comment: What was the creature like?

Comment: Just a similar ending in "The Dark Side of the Moon": https://youtu.be/nX97ggb_l8Q?t=370

Comment: Any chance that it is the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/205005/movie-with-a-returning-probe-satellite-an-alien-infection-and-a-nuke-at-the-en ?

Comment: Definetly a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/205005/movie-with-a-returning-probe-satellite-an-alien-infection-and-a-nuke-at-the-en

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Movie with a returning probe/satellite, an alien infection, and a nuke at the end](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/205005/movie-with-a-returning-probe-satellite-an-alien-infection-and-a-nuke-at-the-en)

Comment: @Dosco Jones - We don't close story-ID threads as dupes unless the two questions being associated are both confirmed to be asking about the same story by the respective OPs. There's no such confirmation from the OP in regard to this question, hence this question should be left open.