# Movie where an alien pod landed at an arctic base

Tags: story-identification, aliens

These people are at an arctic base, at least I think it was set in the arctic. I know it was extremely rural/barren. But this alien pod landed and the crew were terrified of it except for one person, we'll call him B, who believed the alien was gentle and wasn't aware that it could / was causing harm.

I remember they killed the alien and B was horrified and said something about how the alien didn't mean any harm. Another crew member says something along the lines of "I pray you're correct. Because another pod just landed in [insert location]" and it ends on that cliffhanger where you don't know if it's the beginning of an alien invasion or if the creature really was wrongly murdered.

I remember seeing it on TV sometime around 2000-2004. It definitely wasn't *The Thing*, just some obscure film I just happened to see.

Answer (score 14):

#### [*Lifeform*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116646/) (aka *Intruder*/*Invader*) 1996

> When the Viking space capsule suddenly returns to Earth from its long ago trip to Mars, it brings with it an intelligent visitor that is part "Alien" and part "ET". Encased in armor, it extends a humanlike form from its shell to examine its surroundings and shows an interest in humans including a soft caress of a female scientist prior to the Army killing it. This only enrages its sibling.

Comment: Now accept the answer for everybody to see that it is the correct answer.

Comment: it said i have to wait 2 days to accept my own answer?? i guess to make sure i'm not a spam bot or something. i'll keep the page open so i dont forget to come back and verify this one. thank you again for helping!!

Comment: @toxxicpill: It's only 48 hours for self-answers. Otherwise, it's a few minutes at most.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Which is the opposite of how it _should_ work. But hey, that's Stack Exchange for you!

Comment: @user91988: Yeah... if you got points for accepting your own answer, I could see it, but writing a question, and immediately answering it, is fair game. I think the idea behind it is that if you write your own answer, you're already biased toward it being right, so the 48 hours gives you a cool-down period to consider other answers that come in (less relevant for `story-identification` but very apropos for SE's original aim of coding).

Comment: @FuzzyBoots ohhhhh that makes so much sense! I hadn't thought of it that way, but it makes the most sense imo. forcing you to wait for other interaction and possible answers. it wasn't my intention to immediately answer my own question, i just went into research mode and happened to luck up and find a screencap that i KNEW was the alien i remembered this time. like, after 15 years of wondering wtf i watched, i know lol